# Android Backup Service - Backup of contacts in HTC device and restore on HTC Desire2

Tags: android, backup, restore, android-backup-service

I have a usecase where I need to perform backup of contacts from one device (HTC magic) and restore on a different device (HTC Desire2).

I tried using the [Android Backup API's](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/backup.html), but during my testing I found that we cannot restore the data on different device (HTC Desire2). But I was able to successfully restore on the data on the same device (HTC magic).

Few queries:

1. Is there a way I can restore the data on a different device ?
2. I want to explicitly call the `requestRestore()` API of BackupManager, but when I call the API it throws `SecurityException` even though I have the `android.permission.BACKUP` permission in manifest. Do we need to sign application with platform certificates ?

Comment: Hey...i am facing the same issue . did you find the way to do this